# View Models: Data Duplication VS Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Im learning MVC and have had a thought which i would like some opinions on please.

Im making a simple social network to learn MVC on. There are Users, and Posts. Each user can have many posts on their wall (from themselves and other users). These are my Domain Models

```
**USER**
UserID
Username
First Name
Second Name
WallID

**POST**
PostID
WallID (id of user who's wall has been posted to)
UserID (user who posted)
PostConent
```

Now Im trying to understand viewmodels. and i dont think i understand them properly, from what i understand at the moment to get the user information for the authors of the posts i would make two new models to combine the data on a page:

```
**POSTExtended**
PostID
WallID (id of user who's wall has been posted to)
UserID (user who posted)
PostConent
Username
FirstName
SurName

**WallViewModel**
PostExtended postExtended = new PostExtended
User user = new User
```

Now im not sure how to populate this. My best guess at the moment sounds like it would work - but does certainly not sound right!

I would create a controller bound to wallViewModel.

I would then Query the DB to get all posts for The relevant WallID and store them in a object List.

I would then use a foreach loop to query the users table for each post in the list - To get the users name and username for that PostID, and add them to a new PostExtended object (With the other data from the original post object), and store them in a postExtended object list.

I would then hit the DB to get the user object for the wallViewModel (the user who's wall the posts belong to) so i can display their name in the title etc etc.

I would then add the User Object and add the PostExtended Object List to a WallViewModel object. And send that object to the view.

Now this sounds wrong to me because as far as i can tell this will mean hitting the database a separate time for every post to get the users name.

Could someone shed some light onto this please. It sounds like there must be an easier way to do this! (If this is the right way, then would it be better to just duplicate data in the posts table to save hitting the database every time in the loop?).

Hope this is understandable! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view models are a way to combine different sources of data and send custom information to the view.  In this case what you need is a model that has a single user but a list of posts.  something like this

```
** WallViewModel **
User user
List<User> userList
List<Post> posts
```

this way you have all of the posts for that user but the user information is only there one time and not duplicated.  Let me know if you have any questions

Edit:

I understand now.  Since you have multiple users and multiple posts on each page I would send the page owner (single) and a list of users that have posts on the page.  Then loop through the posts and from the user id on the post you can select the corresponding users information from the userList.  Hopefully this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time - most appriciated. Perhaps i was not clear. Each post has an author, which is stored as UserID in the Posts Table. I need to get the authors(users) information for each post - which will be different users to the user who's wall it is. Pretty much the same as users posting on a friends facebook wall. Would your method bring across all of the users usernames?

Comment: His method is a full control method, your ViewModel will contain any data that you want to pass to your view. You define what you need to send to the View. If you need information about the logged in user and then also information about posts from any user, how you define your view gives you full control.

Comment: @Matt So if i understand correctly - i would get the posts list, then from the UserID's in that posts list query the DB to get a UsersList (people that have their user ID's in the posts list). Then get the users information from the users list?

Comment: Since you have a wall id on your users and posts, you should be able to run just 2 queries to grab all of the posts and users that go on that wall, put them in the view model and pass them to the view.  You can't assume that the wall owner will have posted so you may need to query separately for them

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Matt Bodily's answer, your ViewModel will be something like:

```
public class LoggedInUserViewModel
{
   property int UserId;
   property string UserName;
   property List<ViewModelPosts> Posts;
}

public class ViewModelPosts
{
   property int AuthorUserId;
   property string AuthorName;
   property string Message;
   property DateTime CreatedDate;
}
```

In your controller you will simply create a new instance of the LoggedInUserViewModel and populate it correctly with a database call and a foreach loop for the posts/messages. Each iteration of your foreach will create a new instance of a ViewModelPosts and add that populated instance to the LoggedInUserViewModel List property.

It is possible to just pass your model classes directly to the View but this will not accommodate the Views context well. The View is looking/expecting to combine data from your database in a more meaningful way thus ViewModels help make this translation between the basic structure of your model/database and the more complex structure your View desires by combining model classes that relate to each other in a meaningful way in your controller without your View having to have any understanding of the actual data relationship in your database/model.

Comment: Thank you brian. Your explanation helped my understanding of matts solution.

Comment: No problem! Glad you have a better understanding, that always feels good ;).