# Confused between Entity classes Generated By VS and the View Model Class for specific display of Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4 and for the last few days I am working on a MVC project. I am working with Entity Framework. I am using Database first approach. So I used VS feature of automatically generating Entity classes based on schema. Earlier I had asked following question on stackoverflow : [Can I project the result of my query to the model generated by EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167354/can-i-project-the-result-of-my-query-to-the-model-generated-by-ef) 
  The suggestions given were mainly based on creating `View Model` classes. 
I am getting confused about the benefits that I get from creating View Model classes except Projecting my own selected columns. 
For `Creation`, `Deletion` and `Update` the generated Entity Classes works fine. I use my View Model class only if I had to display list of records to users. Also note that my `VM classes` are almost duplicates of the generated `Entity Classes`.

I often run into following problem :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Edit")]
        public ActionResult EditService_POST(SERVICES service)
        {
            DAL lib = new VFS_DAL();
            int state = lib.UpdateService(service);

            if (state == 1)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { service_name = service.NAME });
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Edit")]
        public ActionResult EditService(string service_name)
        {
            DAL lib = new DAL();

            ServicesVM service = lib.GetServiceDetails(service_name); // This method Returns Object of TYPE ServicesVM which I had created for displaying service details, But for Editing I need Object of type Context_Services so I had to write another method that returns object of type Context_Services. Both are same and cause code redundancy. 

            return View("EditService",service);
        }
```

How do I handle such situations. Just for Displaying few selected columns I have to create Vew Model classes or there are other uses of it as well ?

How can I handle above mentioned situations so that I do-not run into the problem of switching between Entity-Framework Generated classes and View Model Classes which is basically code duplication.
What are the best practices in this regards.

Any reading suggestions like books and links are welcomed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

View models should reflect data attributes for validation that may or may not be useful on your base entity framework classes. Since the classes in some cases are similar or the same auto mapper could be used to map between entity framework classes and view model classes.

Comment: See this link as well for another example of data vs view model http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027841/view-models-data-duplication-vs-performance?rq=1